# SQL Server conn string. w/ remote machine requires IP:PORT and SQLPORT

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

My problem is trying to create a connection string in C# which connects to a SQL Server 2012 database remotely. I can successfully do this if the machine hosting the SQL Server does not require a port number to navigate to. Now that we have re-routed our ip's a little, the ip to the machine hosting SQL Server is XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:16500, where SQL Server is still listening on default port 1433.

I understand you can specify the port number that the SQL Server instance is using like so;

```
data source=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;initial catalog=Order;User ID=test1;Password=test1;");
```

Our problem is, that our remote machine is not just an IP. It is an IP and a port.

`XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:16500` would manually navigate to the desired PC, ignoring the port number would take you to another machine. We are trying to accomplish something like this;

```
data source=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:16500,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;initial catalog=Order;User ID=test1;Password=test1;");
```

I cannot find for the life of me how to do this. I want to set my data source to a remote IP:PORT, as well as set the port SQL Server will be listening on (I understand 1433 is the default, but in some cases we may have to change it, so it needs to be there for the future)

I have tried;

```
data source=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:16500,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;initial catalog=Order;User ID=test1;Password=test1;");
```

ERROR:

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occured while
>   establishing a connection to the SQL Server...*

```
data source=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:16500;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;initial catalog=Order;User ID=test1;Password=test1;");
```

ERROR:

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occured while
>   establishing a connection to the SQL Server...*

```
data source=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,16500;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;initial catalog=Order;User ID=test1;Password=test1;");
```

ERROR:

> *A connection was successfully established with the server, but then
>   an error occurred durring the pre-login handshake. (Provider: TCP
>   Provider, error:0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host.)*

Here it seems I am just connecting to the wrong server, trying to use port 16500 for SQL Server, which is not correct.

Can anyone please shine some light, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the IP address you have is actually a NAT device that forwards the traffic to another machine base on the port that was used to connect to it. If this is the case, you need to get your NAT administrator to create a public port on the NAT that will be forwarded to port 1433 on your SQL Server machine. Any port forwarding always only forwards to a single port, so what you were trying to do cannot work without that new forwarding rule being set up.

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying does not make sense from a network perspective:
A host by definition is tied to one or more IP addressed, not to an IP:Port combination.

I would agree with Sebastian, it sounds like your network administrator set a NAT or some other type of routing/firewall so that connecting (by TCP?) to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:16500 on the router/firewall/NAT would forward the connection to some application listening on some port of  the SQL server machine (a remote desktop application perhaps.)

You need to request port forwarding to the sql server to be configured as Sebastian suggested. Another option would be to setup an SSH server to listen on the already forwarded port (or a different one) then you (or your network administrator) could set up secure tunnels to whichever applications are needed without having to change the firewall configuration.

Having forwarding done by a NAT/Router/Firewall on multiple ports for multiple applications or using SHH to tunnel on a single port each has its advantages and drawbacks. Talk to your network administrator he should be able to gauge which is the better option for your case.

Answer (score 0):

> MS SQL Server is XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:16500, where MS SQL is still listening on default port 1433.

Um.. no.. The NAT device is at XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX which is forwarding port 16500 to your SQL Server.  You don't know the SQL server IP address, as that address is completely inaccessible to your application because the NAT is between you and it.  Nor do you know/care what port number SQL server is installed on: that's the NATs job.

Therefore the proper connection string to use is:

```
data source=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,16500;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;initial catalog=Order;User ID=test1;Password=test1;";
```

Now, you stated you received an error here.  That error indicates that you have connected successfully but that there is some other issue going on.  Things that could cause this include:

- SQL server has hit it's connection limit (most likely)
- SQL server is requiring an encrypted connection but that's not what you are trying to establish
- a bad ssl certificate is being used
- SQL server is expecting windows authentication only, which you aren't using
- TCP/IP connections aren't enabled on the SQL Server
- Data compression between you and the NAT or the NAT and the SQL server.
- NAT screwing with the connection info before it gets to the SQL server (certainly possible with a misconfigured NAT).
- SynAttackProtect is turned on somewhere and you have tried so many things it's kicked you out.
- There are enough delays between the NAT and the SQL server to cause SQL Server to kick out the connection.
- and many many more...

Essentially there is a network issue here and it's not due to the port number.  You have to get the network admin involved to see what's going on.

I'd lay money down that the problem is EITHER a configuration issue on the SQL server to artificially limit the number of connections or the NAT is jacking the request before it is properly forwarded to the DB server.

see some of the following:
http://betav.com/blog/billva/2008/11/solution-forcibly-closed-sql-s.html
http://arshpreet9.wordpress.com/category/sql-errorsbug-fixes/