# ConnectionString for remote SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

This is the case, I want to connect to SQL2008R2 that is located on a remote server, I can enter to the server remotely and after I login *as an admin* on windows I work on the SQL Server MS (The connection to SQL is through Windows Authentification).

I am working on a WinForms App that needs connection with SQL, I have tried several connectionString without success, for example:

```
public static string strCon = @"Server=190.xxx.xxx.xxx\ServerName,1433;Database=DataBaseName;Integrated Security=false;User ID=User;Password=Pass";

public static string strCon = @"Data Source=190.xxx.xxx.xxx\ServerName,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;User ID=User;Password=Pass;
```

Am I missing something? Should I do something else, before I try to connect?

I think I have a mess with the windows authentification thing, can I bypass it and connect directly to the SQL?

Note that remote connection is enabled on the server, and I checked the port being 1433.

EDIT:

While I was looking for a solution I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058155/sql-server-conn-string-w-remote-machine-requires-ipport-and-sqlport?rq=1) and I realized that when I connect remotely to the server I use a port (190.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy).  My problem is right there, isn't it?

EDIT2: 
      My solution: the connectionString I was using was alright, the problem was the port. I opened it for my office IP and everythings works like a charm.

Comment: `Integrated Security=false` should be `Integrated Security=true`. and drop the username and password.

Comment: Here's a quick way to create connection strings https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38h511e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx.  Note you have to remove the provider part when using it in C#.

Comment: @juharr: that's an ancient link. It's over a decade old and way out of date.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you use the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, which allows you to configure connection strings through properties and guarantees that valid connection strings are created.

Use it like this:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder b = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
b.DataSource = "190.xxx.xxx.xxx\ServerName";
b.InitialCatalog = "DataBaseName";
b.IntegratedSecurity = false;
b.UserId = "...";
b.Password = "...";

string connectionString = b.ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect with **Windows authentication** you should be using:

```
public static string strCon = @"Data Source=190.xxx.xxx.xxx\ServerName,1433;Database=DataBaseName;Integrated Security=True";
```

Also note that 1433 is the default sql port so you don't have to specify it.
You could just write:

```
public static string strCon = @"Data Source=190.xxx.xxx.xxx\ServerName;Database=DataBaseName;Integrated Security=True";
```

In that case `User Name` and `Password` should not be specified because it will use the Windows account of your current session.

You can find more details regarding SQL Server connection string [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to connect with Windows Authentication, because when I use the SQL through remote connection I log in as an Admin. Also I think I've read that you can't include the Windows login information inside the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about IntegratedSecurity attribute if you want connect with user id and password

```
public static string strCon = @"Data Source=190.xxx.xxx.xxx\ServerName,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;Integrated Security=False;User ID=User;Password=Pass;
```

otherwise:

```
public static string strCon = @"Data Source=190.xxx.xxx.xxx\ServerName,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;Integrated Security=True;
```